# news feed textarea showing in ie

Tags: html, textarea

The scrolling news feed like text the should show up in the textarea is not showing in ie, though it works in chrome.  When I run it in ie it shows the textarea but it does not display text.  The actual website that I am correcting is: wirqfm.org

```
<textarea style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; border-color: rgb(16, 91, 99); resize: none; background-color: rgb(16, 91, 99); color: rgb(255, 211, 78); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;" name="news2" cols="50" rows="3" wrap="virtual" readonly=""></textarea>
</form>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

document.news.news2.style.background = '105b63';
document.news.news2.style.color = 'FFD34E';

var newsText = new Array();
//initializes the text to be printed
//this is all of the banner text the scrolls across the index.html page
newsText[0] = "Welcome to the WIRQ";
newsText[1] = "The longest running high school radio station in the country providing quality alternative music for over 50 years";
newsText[2] = "Our phone number is now (585) 336-0740.  Give us a call if you have ";

var ttloop = 0;    // Repeat forever? (1 = True; 0 = False)
var tspeed = 75;   // Typing speed in milliseconds (larger number = slower)
var tdelay = 2500; // Time delay between newsTexts in milliseconds

var dwAText, cnews=0, eline=0, cchar=0, mxText;

function doNews() {

 mxText = newsText.length - 1;  //maximum text length
 dwAText = newsText[cnews];  //value of the current news

 setTimeout("addChar()",1000)
}

function addNews() {

 cnews += 1; //increment current news

 if (cnews <= mxText) {  //if current news hasn't surpassed the maximum news array length
     dwAText = newsText[cnews];
     if (dwAText.length != 0) {
     document.news.news2.value = "";  //reset text value of the box
     eline = 0;  //start new line
     setTimeout("addChar()",tspeed)
     }
  }
}

function addChar() {

  if (eline!=1) { //if the line isn't finished
     if (cchar != dwAText.length) {
     nmttxt = "";
     for (var k=0; k<=cchar;k++)
           nmttxt += dwAText.charAt(k);  //put desired amount of characters in the current news

     document.news.news2.value = nmttxt;
     cchar += 1;  //increment the current character
     if (cchar != dwAText.length)  //if it hasn't reached the message end, append typing symbol
           document.news.news2.value += "_";
     } else {  //if the line has finished, reset the current character and mark that the line is finished
     cchar = 0;
     eline = 1;
     }
     if (mxText==cnews && eline!=0 && ttloop!=0) {  //if all the news is over, the endline is reached, and looping is on, repeat
     cnews = -1; setTimeout("addNews()",tdelay*4);
     } else setTimeout("addChar()",tspeed);
  } else {  //if the line has been MARKED as being finished, show the next news segment
     setTimeout("addNews()",tdelay)
  }
}

doNews()

  </script>
```